# Widget Creation

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt

I want to create a custome widget. Please help by giving some idea.

My intention is to make a Listwidget which shows some Information and when clicking particulat row it have to show the details coresponding to that row  by creating a new area immediately below the selected row and pull the other rows below the selected row to down after the created new area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure If I understand your question right, but a [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html) might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to show those details [QToolBox](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtoolbox.html#details) might be more appropriate than [QTreeWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qtreewidget.html#details).